# how to set chrome in Chinese when I use chromedriver to open it?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to set the chrome browser in Chinese when using chromedriver to open       it?

> When using chromedriver to open chrome, its default language is English, how can I set it in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding Chrome's [command line switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches) [`--lang`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#lang).

Basically, all you need is starting [`ChromeDriver`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html) with an [`ChromeOptions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html) argument `--lang=zh`, see API for details.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--lang=zh");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```